# SyntaxError in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a json file which is loading by fetch() request and there is this error:
`SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 1079119 of the JSON data"`. Is there any formatter to find exact line and column that is in error message?

Comment: Check your dev tools - network tab. It should show the response received in string format.

Comment: Hi @ jdc91. I can see the response in network tab, but Is it possible to find `line 1 column 1079119 ` of json data?

Comment: Can you post here the response you are getting?

Comment: My response is an array by almost 1000 object.

Comment: Do you want to send you one of the object?

Comment: Try this site https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189763/discussion-between-jdc91-and-bita).